# using a virtual attribute as a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to be able to have a virtual attribute on a non-database model that is a hash. I just can't figure out what the syntax is for adding and removing items from this hash:

If I define:

```
attr_accessor :foo, :bar
```

then in a method in the model, I can use:

```
self.foo = "x"
```

But I can't say:

```
self.bar["item"] = "value"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
self.bar = Hash.new
self.bar["item"] = "value"
```

Comment: ahhhh. I presume that I should say self.bar = Hash.new in the constructor ?

Comment: Honestly I am just guessing hoping it will save you time.  If it works initialize it.

Comment: this worked for me. I added the self.bar = Hash.new into the initialize method and it worked. Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourModel
  def bar
    @bar ||= Hash.new
  end

  def foo
    bar["item"] = "value"
  end
end
```

but classic approach would be:

```
class YourModel
  def initialize
    @bar = Hash.new
  end

  def foo
    @bar["item"] = "value"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html), [Hash with Indifferent Access](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) or [Active Model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model).

Comment: I should have said that I use ActiveModel. I have the following in the  code "include ActiveModel::Validations"

Comment: I want to use ActiveModel as I am using the validation to ensure data passed is present and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling:

```
attr_accessor :foo, :bar
```

on your class, Ruby does something like the following behind the curtains:

```
def foo
  return @foo
end
def foo=(val)
  @foo = val
end

def bar
  return @bar
end
def bar=(val)
  @bar = val
end
```

The methods #foo and #bar are just returning the instance variables and #foo= and #bar= just set them. So if you want one of them to contain a Hash, you have to assign this Hash somewhere.

My favorite solution would be the following:

```
class YourModel

  # generate the default accessor methods
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar

  # overwrite #bar so that it always returns a hash
  def bar
    @bar ||= {}
  end

end
```